# How to split one pandas dataframe column which contains combined values to several columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider I have a pandas DataFrame like following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Python','p1,p2,p3'],
                   ['Java','j1,j2,j3'],
                   ['C++','c1,c2,c3']], columns=['name','features'])
```

So that it looks like:

```
         name  features
    0  Python  p1,p2,p3,p4,p5
    1    Java  j1,j2,j3
    2     C++  c1,c2,c3
```

I would like to split 'features' column (but only keeping the first 3 features, so 'p1,p2,p3,p4,p5' will become 'p1,p2,p3'), so my final expected DataFrame will be:

```
          name    feature1 feature2  feature3
    0     Python  p1       p2        p3
    1     Java    j1       j2        j3
    2     C++     c1       c2        c3
```

How should I do it? Thanks.

I searched several SO answers related to split columns, but none of them meet my requirements. I am a new learner of pandas. Feel free to edit the question if it is not well formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) od new `df` created by [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) of extracted column by [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html), select only first `3` columns by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and last add [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = df.join(df.pop('features').str.split(',',expand=True).iloc[:, :3].add_prefix('feature'))
print (df)
     name feature0 feature1 feature2
0  Python       p1       p2       p3
1    Java       j1       j2       j3
2     C++       c1       c2       c3
```

What is same as solution with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = df.drop('features', axis=1).join(df['features'].str.split(',', expand=True).iloc[:, :3]
                                                    .add_prefix('feature'))
print (df)
     name feature0 feature1 feature2
0  Python       p1       p2       p3
1    Java       j1       j2       j3
2     C++       c1       c2       c3
```

Also if need count from `1` use `rename`:

```
f = lambda x: 'feature' + str(x + 1)
df = df.join(df.pop('features').str.split(',', expand=True).iloc[:, :3].rename(columns=f))
print (df)

     name feature1 feature2 feature3
0  Python       p1       p2       p3
1    Java       j1       j2       j3
2     C++       c1       c2       c3
```

Comment: @ayhan - Thank you, I use sample data without values of next column.